# Type mismatch when adding YouTubePlayerSupportFragment fragment to Fragment Transaction

Tags: android, android-fragments, classcastexception, android-youtube-api

I am trying to use the YouTubePlayerSupportFragment inside my own fragment that I created. When trying to add it into the childFragmentManager's fragment transaction, I get a type cast error saying that the object's type needs to be Fragment and not YouTubePlayerSupportFragment. I am adding it into the fragment transaction so that I can choose when to hide or show the fragment. Everything I have seen online and written in Java works the same way my code works unless it has something to do with Kotlin?

Fragment.xml

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/youtube_player_fragment"
        android:name="com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerSupportFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Fragment.kt

```
import android.os.Bundle
import android.text.SpannableString
import android.text.style.BulletSpan
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.ImageView
import android.widget.LinearLayout
import android.widget.TextView
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeInitializationResult
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayer
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerSupportFragment
class ExpandedItemFragment(private val hasVideo: Boolean) : Fragment(), YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener {
    private lateinit var mosquitoVideo: YouTubePlayerSupportFragment

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.expanded_item, container, false
        )
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        initializeLayout()
    }

    private fun initializeLayout() {
        mosquitoVideo = YouTubePlayerSupportFragment.newInstance()
        childFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.youtube_player_fragment, mosquitoVideo) //Type cast error happening here
        if (hasVideo) {
            mosquitoVideo.initialize(getString(R.string.google_api_key), this)
        }
    }
override fun onInitializationSuccess(
        provider: YouTubePlayer.Provider,
        youTubePlayer: YouTubePlayer,
        b: Boolean
    ) {
        if (!b) {
            youTubePlayer.cueVideo("rD8SmacBUcU")
        }
    }

    override fun onInitializationFailure(
        provider: YouTubePlayer.Provider,
        youTubeInitializationResult: YouTubeInitializationResult
    ) {
        Toast.makeText(activity, "Youtube video failed to play", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
```

Comment: Have you enabled Jetifier? That automatically translates `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` into `androidx.fragment.app.Fragment` instances (you are using AndroidX Fragments, right?)

Comment: Yes I am to your second question, I'm not sure if Jetifier is enabled. How would you do that?

Comment: You'd want to double check to make sure you followed the [Migrating to AndroidX docs](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate#migrate_an_existing_project_using_android_studio)

Comment: I just checked my gradle.properties and jetifier is enabled

Comment: So what is it that I need to fix since jetifier is enabled?

Comment: Can you add all of your import statements for your `ExpandedItemFragment`?

Comment: Updated with import statements.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [YouTube Player Support Fragment crashes when user selects to view in full screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58923657/youtube-player-support-fragment-crashes-when-user-selects-to-view-in-full-screen)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this component here it implements web frame 
 https://github.com/PierfrancescoSoffritti/android-youtube-player

add to build.grandle

```
dependencies {
     implementation 'com.pierfrancescosoffritti.androidyoutubeplayer:core:10.0.5'
        }
```

add to you XML

```
<com.pierfrancescosoffritti.androidyoutubeplayer.core.player.views.YouTubePlayerView
        android:id="@+id/youtube_player_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       />
```

load video

```
YouTubePlayerView youTubePlayerView = findViewById(R.id.youtube_player_view);


youTubePlayerView.addYouTubePlayerListener(new AbstractYouTubePlayerListener() {
  @Override
  public void onReady(@NonNull YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer) {
    String videoId = "rD8SmacBUcU";
    youTubePlayer.loadVideo(videoId, 0);
  }
});
```

Comment: I need to convert this code to Kotlin and when I did I tried using this method header: "override fun onReady() {}" but it says that it overrides nothing and it needs the override key or the function is never called.

Comment: I figured out what was not working. There is no need to begin a transaction on the YouTubePlayerSupportFragment object. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58925101/5715663