# YouTube Player Support Fragment crashes when user selects to view in full screen

Tags: android, kotlin, android-youtube-api, android-fullscreen

I have implemented YouTubePlayerSupportFragment API inside my own fragment instead of in an activity. The video does play normally, but when the user selects to view the video in full screen from YouTube's provided media controls, the app orients to landscape, shows a black loading screen and then immediately crashes.

ExpandedItem.layout

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
 <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/youtube_layout_container"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="gone"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/close_button">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/youtube_player_fragment"
        android:name="com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerSupportFragment"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

ExpandedItemFragment.kt

```
import android.os.Bundle
import android.text.SpannableString
import android.text.style.BulletSpan
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.ImageView
import android.widget.LinearLayout
import android.widget.TextView
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeInitializationResult
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayer
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerSupportFragment
class ExpandedItemFragment(private val hasVideo: Boolean) : Fragment(), YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener {
    private lateinit var mosquitoVideo: YouTubePlayerSupportFragment

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.expanded_item, container, false
        )
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        initializeLayout()
    }

    private fun initializeLayout() {
        if (hasVideo) {
           youTubeLayoutContainer.visibility = View.VISIBLE
           mosquitoVideo =
              childFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.youtube_player_fragment) as YouTubePlayerSupportFragment
           mosquitoVideo.initialize(getString(R.string.google_api_key), this)
        }
    }
override fun onInitializationSuccess(
        provider: YouTubePlayer.Provider,
        youTubePlayer: YouTubePlayer,
        b: Boolean
    ) {
        if (!b) {
            youTubePlayer.cueVideo("rD8SmacBUcU")
        }
    }

    override fun onInitializationFailure(
        provider: YouTubePlayer.Provider,
        youTubeInitializationResult: YouTubeInitializationResult
    ) {
        Toast.makeText(activity, "Youtube video failed to play", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
```

The ExpandedItemFragment does inflate normally when the video is not in full screen yet, but after the user selects it to be in full screen, the app crashes. The exception being thrown is:

```
Caused by: androidx.fragment.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.example.mosquitotracker.ExpandedItemFragment: could not find Fragment constructor
```

The exception is located in my MainActivity.kt at

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
```

Comment: The error message is saying that you need to have a non argument constructor by default - that's how FragmentManager creates Fragments after configuration changes or process death and recreation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why my app was crashing when the user selects to put the youtube video into fullscreen mode was that the YouTubePlayerSupportFragment auto rotates to landscape mode. I wasn't handling configuration changes properly in the activity that inflated my fragment so it was having issues trying to re-inflate the fragment and it crashed my app. For anyone who has similar issues, I suggest either handling configuration changes manually or adding `android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden` to whichever activity holds a fragment that inflates YouTubePlayerSupportFragment inside of it. The code I provided in my question will work for anyone who is trying to implement YouTubePlayerSupportFragment inside of a fragment rather than an activity.

Comment: You've just papered over the problem - you're still going to hit the same exception when your process dies and is recreated (for example, if you use the Developer Option to 'Don't keep activities')

Answer (score -2):

YouTubePlayer component doesn't work well with fragments, you should to open in a activity only for the video, but my advice to you is to use this component here https://github.com/PierfrancescoSoffritti/android-youtube-player

add to build.grandle

```
dependencies {
     implementation 'com.pierfrancescosoffritti.androidyoutubeplayer:core:10.0.5'
        }
```

add to you XML

```
<com.pierfrancescosoffritti.androidyoutubeplayer.core.player.views.YouTubePlayerView
        android:id="@+id/youtube_player_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       />
```

load video

```
YouTubePlayerView youTubePlayerView = findViewById(R.id.youtube_player_view);


youTubePlayerView.addYouTubePlayerListener(new AbstractYouTubePlayerListener() {
  @Override
  public void onReady(@NonNull YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer) {
    String videoId = "rD8SmacBUcU";
    youTubePlayer.loadVideo(videoId, 0);
  }
});
```

This component implements web frame you don't need to generate an access key to use YoutTube API, negative point run advertise

Comment: I would have done it an activity as that seems to be the easiest solution, but because of how my app is written for optimization purposes for other features, I have to use it within a fragment. What is bad about this solution?

Comment: I figured out the reason why and this answer does not help.

Comment: The project I did, I had a problem when I play YoutubePlayer inside a fragment if you are using a youtube inside an activity works well, but if you need put tabs for example with other videos don't work, just one player by Activity